# How can I show 3 entries at random from within the next 10

Tags: templating, entries, limit

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('entertainmentEvents').status('live','pending').search('entertainmentBanner:*').order('RAND()').limit(3) %}
```

This is working to show 3 random entries from the full list of all entries with the entertainmentBanner field populated. How would I limit it to the first ten entries by entry date and then 3 at random from within them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Craft's [`shuffle()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/functions#shuffle) function to randomize your `postDate` ordered array of entry models:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'entertainmentEvents',
    entertainmentBanner: ':notempty:',
    status: 'live, pending',
    order: 'postDate desc',
    limit: 10
}) %}

{% set entries = shuffle(entries) %}

{% for entry in entries|slice(0, 3) %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it! I'd update your answer to show how you would limit your 'entries' to 3?

Comment: Ouups, totally missed that part. Thanks Jamie.

Comment: @JamieWade carlcs is an answer ninja.

Comment: @BradBell I'll be on my guard next time.

Comment: Perfect. And in production already. Thanks @carlcs